# encoded nsdata utf8 json, with accented char in ios

Tags: ios, json, utf-8, nsstring, non-ascii-characters

i make a post request to a webserver that answer me with a JSON, this is the header of the response :

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 826
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 04 Feb 2015 05:53:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0w0mile5232yoqqdlcdomwgf; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

i parse the data response (NSURLConnection) and serialize the json :

```
NSArray *arrayFromServer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromServerArray options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"string: %@",arrayFromServer);
```

output :

```
string: (
    {
    altitude = 0;
    battery = 100;
    "dev_last_contact" = 1423031944;
    "device_end_licence" = 1430398189;
    "device_type" = hw;
    "email_notification" = 0;
    "end_user_type" = 0;
    "fstk_cnt" = 15;
    "fstk_ts" = 0;
    heading = 0;
    id = 62;
    imei = 0123456789APPLE;
    inversegeo = "gsm_position ";
    label = "Test\Ufffd";
    latitude = "45.503731";
    "licence_level" = 2;
    "licence_status" = valid;
    "licence_type" = 1;
    longitude = "11.90365";
    "md5_image" = CA137B2CB710BC15C87BC6A54D305A2B;
    "movement_alert" = 0;
    "on_movement" = 0;
    "pos_acy" = 1977;
    "push_notification" = 0;
    refresh = 30;
    "req_pos_cnt" = 0;
    "req_pos_ts" = 0;
    rup = "user_device_list.aspx";
    "secure_area" = 0;
    "serial_nr" = IOS;
    speed = 0;
    "text_notification" = 0;
    timestamp = 1423031944;
    "url_image" = "http://XXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/AppImages/1422966751507_62.jpg";
}
)
```

then i create the objectsArray like this:

```
devicesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *eachDevice in arrayFromServer)
{
    //NSLog(@"DEVICE: %@",eachDevice);

    Device *device = [[Device alloc] initWithJSONData:eachDevice];

    NSString *device_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[device deviceId]];
    [self.all_devices_id addObject:device_id];

    [devicesArray addObject:device];
}
```

my object is very simple :

```
.h
@interface Device : NSObject
-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;
...

.m
-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    self.deviceId = [[data objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

    NSLog(@"data label : %@",[data objectForKey:@"label"]);

    self.label =  [data objectForKey:@"label"];
...
```

the output is :

```
data label : Test�
```

as you can see the "label" is converted in "Test\Ufffd" and then Test� but should be "Testè" 
i have problem with the accented char, how can i encode this string correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is that the web server is not returning you the right data.

Comment: I will contact the webmaster. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with your code because \Ufffd is unicode for � and not for è. Means your server is returning you the wrong value. the correct unicode for è is \U00e8 you can find it [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm), and for � find [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm). I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok i will contact the server admin , hope they will help me. Thanks for your helpm

Comment: @ilmetu Yes I have checked it by storing your JSON to my local and it worked well. So just contact to your server admin and it will work fine.

Comment: Not yet the server admin said the problem is about my request because in the db the char is \Ufffd ... so its not solved yet but i accept your answer don't worry

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[[data objectForKey:@"label"] UTF8String];
```

before

```
NSString *utf = [[data objectForKey:@"label"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: No, unfortunately doesn't work, NSLog(@"data label : %s",[[data objectForKey:@"label"] UTF8String]);  output: data label : TestÔøΩ
 NSString *utf = [[data objectForKey:@"label"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; output : data label : Test�