# is there any solution to convert all encoded words to utf-8 encode format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, encoding, utf-8

While working on HTML pages, some words(umlauts) within page are converted into some symbols as shown below:

```
"m�ssen" actual word "müssen".
"regelm��ig �berpr�ft" actual word "regelmäßig überprüft".
"F�rderung" actual word "Förderung".
```

Can anyone please help me out. It would be great help.
How can i convert all such words using any language/script.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: done google, but no result found, can you please tell some keywords to search @Dsafds

Comment: "Convert To Utf-8"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

Comment: no solution, Please any other option

Comment: You might have to award this a bounty.... so users can get more attention towards this question, and you will have a high probability to get your question anwsered.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like,

```
NSString *utf = [yourString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315273/encoded-nsdata-utf8-json-with-accented-char-in-ios) for more detail.

hope this will help :)